# Why is my Applescript to add a background image to a .dmg folder getting the size wrong?

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm using the following Applescript to set up a .dmg folder's settings, icon spacing, and so on:

```
on run argv
tell application "Finder"
    set diskname to item 1 of argv
    tell disk diskname
        open
        set current view of container window to icon view
        set toolbar visible of container window to false
        set statusbar visible of container window to false
        set bounds of container window to {400, 100, 900, 699}
        set theViewOptions to the icon view options of container window
        set arrangement of theViewOptions to not arranged
        set icon size of theViewOptions to 100
        set background picture of theViewOptions to file "background.png"
        set file_list to every file
        repeat with i in file_list
            if the name of i is "Applications" then
                set the position of i to {368, 135}
            else if the name of i ends with ".app" then
                set the position of i to {134, 135}
            end if
            -- Change the 7 to change the color: 0 is no label, then red,
            -- orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, or gray.
            set the label index of i to 7
        end repeat
        update without registering applications
        delay 4
    end tell
end tell
end run
```

The window's being set up correctly, with one exception: the 500x600 background.png image is shrunk to about a third of the original size and placed in the upper left corner. I can't explain why this is happening. Any suggestions?

Comment: i'm trying to do the same think to make a background to .dmg, can you show me what is the full code I need?

Answer (score 4):

Boy, this is really st00pid.

I ran into this problem on OS X Lion. It turns out that Lion requires that the background image for a folder be set to 72 DPI. The image I was using was 200 DPI, so Lion scaled it down from its actual pixels.

I re-saved the image with a declared resolution of 72 DPI, and it works perfectly.

Comment: It's not stupid, it's just chosen one way of doing things rather than another. There would be plenty of situations where expanding an image to show every pixel rather than respecting its declared resolution would be unhelpful behaviour.